# How to get sed to take extended regular expressions?

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed, grep

I want to do string replacement using regular expressions in `sed`.  Now, I'm aware that the behavior of `sed` is funky on a Mac.  I've often seen workarounds using `egrep` when I want to just examine a certain pattern in a line.  But, in this case I want to do string replacement.

I want to replace `cp an` and `cp  <tab or newline> an` with `gggg`.  I tried the following, which would work under extended regular expressions:

```
sed -i'_backup' 's/cp\s+an/gggg/g'
```

But of course this does nothing.  I tried `egrep`ping, and of course it picks out the lines with `cp <one or more space characters> an`.

How do I get `sed` to do replacement using extended regular expressions?  Or what is a better way to do replacement using regular expressions?

i'm on mac osx.

Comment: Installing GNU coreutils will give you access to GNU sed. `brew install coreutils` if you have Homebrew already.

Comment: This Q may be more appropriate on the related site http://apple.stackexchange.com (AskDifferent). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Good luck.

Comment: The [man page for `sed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) explains in a section helpfully titled "Sed Regular Expressions". It links to the [re_format man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/re_format.7.html), which explains the features of "modern" (a.k.a. "extended") regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX following command will work for extended regex support:

```
sed -i.backup -E 's/cp[[:blank:]]+an/gggg/g'
```

[POSIX Character Class Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

Comment: Okay I'll try this.  Where do I find documentation for such things as `[[blank]]`?

Comment: Added a reference in answer for POSIC character classes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you want `<newline>` to be handled, you'll need to coax sed a bit.  Your exact requirements aren't too clear to me but the following example illustrates that sed can easily handle certain cases in which a newline is in the "target" regex:

```
$ echo $'cp\nancp an' | sed -E '/cp/{N; s/cp(\n|[[:blank:]])an/gggg/g;}'
gggggggg
```

(Note to non-Mac readers: If your grep does not support `-E`, try `-r` instead.)